# Method to Force C++ Class to be Destructed After Interop Call from C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, interop, destructor

I have the following wrapper to provide access to my C++ DLL from C#

```
#include "Stdafx.h"
#include "Config.h"
#include "Utils.h"
#include "LogicCompiler.h"

extern "C" {
   LIBRARY_EXPORT void GenerateTables(
      const char* version, 
      const char* baseDir, 
      const char** fileList);
} // end extern "C"

void GenerateTables(
   const char* version,
   const char* baseDir, 
   const char** fileList)
{
   std::string strVersion(version);
   std::string strBaseDir(baseDir);
   std::vector<std::string> vFileList = Utils::CharArrayToVector(fileList);
   LogicCompiler* compiler = new LogicCompiler(strVersion, strBaseDir, vFileList);
   compiler->m_PreProcessor->GenerateTables();
}
```

This call works well and `GenerateTables` does its job. The problem is that the destructor for `LogicCompiler* compiler` is never called. Some operation are performed there (clean up etc.). In order to dispose of the `compiler` object and attempt to get the destructor to fire up, I have added `free(compiler);` to the end of the `GenerateTables()` method shown above, but this also does not invoke the destructor.

How can I force the compiler object to be disposed correctly and thus invoke the class destructor?

Thanks for your time.

---

*Edit. The first thing I tried was using `delete compiler;` but this did not compile.*

Comment: You have to use the `delete` operator of course.  Or simply let the compiler take care of it with LogicCompiler compiler(...);

Comment: never mix `new`/`delete` with `malloc()`/`free()` because it's undefined behavior

Comment: @HansPassant, I could not get the code to compile using `delete compiler;`. What do you mean by the second sentence?

Comment: what was the compilation error for `delete compiler;`?

Comment: I'm not going to guess at a "did not compile".  Document your question properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Never ever ever*** use `new` with `free()` or `malloc()` with `delete` because that's the road to programming hell.

Therefore, since you allocated your object with `new` you should free it with `delete`. Using `free()` **doesn't call the object's destructor** (**nor does** `malloc()` **call its constructor)**.

The only time you'd need to use `malloc()`/`free()` in C++ should be when overloading the `new` operator, respectively the `delete` operator. And even then you should use their STL counterparts (`std::malloc()` and `std::free()`)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The first thing I tried was to use `delete` but the compiler would not let me do this...